# Tab completion and arrow keys don't work in GHCI in Git Bash

Tags: windows, haskell, ghci, git-bash

When I open `ghcii.sh` (Glasgow Haskell Compiler Interactive) in Git Bash, normal tab, backspace, and arrow keys don't work as expected.

For example, if I type `:lo` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I'd expect it to complete the statement to `:load`. What instead happens is that the cursor jumps to the right (to the next tab stop, I guess).

Then, if I use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to go back and fill out the command 'manually', this happens:

```
Prelude> :load PrettyJSON.hs

<interactive>:2:1:
    Not in scope: `ad'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `and' (imported from Prelude), `id' (imported from Prelude)

<interactive>:2:4: Not in scope: `PrettyJSON.hs'
```

This is when I'm *lucky*. Sometimes, I can't even <kbd>Backspace</kbd> all the way back, but instead get stuck somewhere to the right of `:lo` (or whatever other command I'm attempting to issue). I can still hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, though, to try again.

The arrow keys don't invoke command history. If I press <kbd>▲</kbd>, the cursor moves up, but I'd have expected it to cycle through my command history.

This issue seems to be related to Git Bash, because GHCI works correctly in PowerShell on the same machine. On other machines where I'm running an earlier version of Git Bash (git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1), I don't have this problem, so it seems to be related to this particular version (git version 2.5.1.windows.1).

My operating system is Windows 10 64-bit. At first I thought that this issue was related to 64-bit Git Bash, because this is the first time I've seen a 64-bit Git Bash on Windows, but I've also tried installing the 32-bit Git Bash, and it exhibits the exact same behaviour.

Is it possible to make GHCI behave correctly in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having received any responses here, I [cross-posted the question to the project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/360).

Apparently, this issue seems to be related to the *mintty* terminal emulator. If you instead install Git Bash with the *ConHost* emulator, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who still comes here after a Google search...

Instead of changing the way *Git Bash* starts up, you can start *GHCi* directly from the *Start* menu (this already runs it using the *Windows Console*). Simply type *GHCi* in the *Start* menu/screen and wait for the result. The bonus is a nice **Haskell icon** in the console title bar :P

You can also try *WinGHCi*, which should already be installed.

Answer (score 3):

This might be due to new features added in the intervening years, but Git Bash comes with [`winpty`](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) and it seems to work well with GHCi for Windows:

```
$ winpty stack ghci
```